# VueJS 2: vee-validate 3 - validation for child components not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

vee-validate version: 3.4.5

So I have a FormBuilder.vue component which builds my form inputs schema based. I have a custom InputSlugify component and I want to have vee-validate validation for it with the required rule.

**The Problem: When I focus the input and leave the focus, I don't receive the error message "field is required". But it works when I use the `<b-form-input>` component directly. (if field.type === 'text')**

How can I get the validation working for the custom component?

Thanks in advance!

Here is a working codesandbox example

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-frost-3yidg?file=/src/components/InputSlugify.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `emit` the `blur` event from your custom component, as vee-validate cannot pick up the event in wrapping components unless you explicitly emit it.

```html
<b-form-input @blur="$emit('blur')" ... />
```

The default `b-form-input` already emits this event which is why it works with it directly.